# Get the longest string from List<Class> using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

What is the fastest way to get the length of the longest string in `name` for the following List:

```
public class test {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}

List<test> l = new List<test>();
```

Using LINQ.

Comment: The fastest you can get is linear, unless you know that your dataset is sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
var longestLenght = l.Max(r => r.name.Length);
```

Not really sure if it is fastest, but that you can do by comparing with others'.

If you wan to get the item with the longest you length you can do:

```
var itemFromListWithMaxLength = l
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.name.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can query it against the `longestLength` retrieved earlier like:

```
var item = l.FirstOrDefault(r => r.name.Length == longestLenght);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in linear time, not likely get any faster unless you know something special about data:

```
int maxLength = l.Max(x => x.name.Length);
```